# reading and writing tokenized and pos_tagged words to a new file

Tags: python, nltk

I have a txt file which contains a news article (i think its stored as a list) and I want to Tokenize the words and tag them and save them into respective files.

i use the nltk library to run the below.

For some reason the code runs but the files are empty. If i were to run only

```
with open(news_file) as f1, open(token_file, "w") as f2, open(tagged_file, "w") as f3:
 f2.writelines(('\n'.join(wt(words)) for words in f1.readlines()))
```

then the new file would have each word of the news article listed on a new line

with the below code i run into a issue at `tokenized = ' '.join(wt(tagged))` which gives an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. I have also tried `str.join` but to no avail

```
with open(news_file) as f1, open(token_file, "w") as f2, open(tagged_file, "w") as f3:
    tagged = pos_tag(f1.readlines())
    tokenized = ' '.join(word_tokenize(tagged))
    for token_words in tokenized:
        print(' '.join(token_words), file=f2)
    for tag_words in tagged:
        print(' '.join(tag_words), file=f3)
#f2.writelines(('\n'.join(wt(words)) for words in f1.readlines()))
```

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't save/load file when they're pickle-able. Using `pickle` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: do u mean save/load file locally on my machine? because i have 2500 news articles each in a txt document

Comment: Pickle is your friend, esp. for small data.